# 'Site Permissions' is broken

Tags: permissions, site, aspx

`Site Settings ---> Site Permissions` leads to a `Sorry, something went wrong` error page throughout my site collection. Could this be an error with `user.aspx` in _layouts?

Answer (score 0):

there could be many problems and it's hard to say what could be the problem in your case. 
did you get a correlationId on the errorpage? 
i would suggest to use [ulsviewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to view the logs and filter on the correlationId if you did get 1.

Comment: No correlation ID. Just:


Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.
Technical Details
Go back to site

Comment: if i remember correctly the 'Technical Details' part is clickable and shows you the correlationid.

Comment: you're welcome, lets hope the logs will tell you more than just 'something went wrong' :)